# Font Awesome not working In cakephp?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Below id my code. i have added font-awesome for cakephp. but in my output the fontawesome not appearing.

**HTML**

```
 <i class="fa fa-institution"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
 .fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what the actual problem is or why this is relevant to CakePHP. Is your CSS getting included? Show how you are including Font Awesome in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you're giving this. In html link or button.

1. Check whether you properly included the font awesome or not
2. If you're as link means
    `$this->Html->link("<i class='fa fa-users'></i>", [action here], ['escape' => false])`

And i'm using font awesome icons for my cakphp 3 project also. its working fine for me

Comment: <?= $this->Html->link(__("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Add Team"), ['action' => 'add'], ['class' => 'add', 'escape' => false]); ?> This is code i used. Please check your font awesome included properly or not.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing I noticed is that you might have forgotten to copy the fonts folder, it should be placed in the webroot directory. Since, you confirmed that it is showing the square boxes instead of the icon, I would advice you copy the fonts folder to the proper place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you Copy the webfonts folder from FontAwesome extract and place it into your project one directory above to your all.min.css file. This way it can automatically find the available fonts.

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCQMT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For Font Awesome 6 in Cakephp 4, you will need to :

1. Copy the **css** files into your `webroot/css` folder
2. Copy the **js** files into your `webroot/js` folder
3. Copy the **webfonts** files into your `webroot/webfonts` folder. Do not put them in the `font` folder.

In your code, load the js & css files as such.

```
echo $this->Html->css('fontawesome.min');
echo $this->Html->script('all.js');
```